# Haskell [IO Int] to [IO Char] output

Tags: haskell, io

With using `randomRIO (0, 5 :: Int)` I create a list of type [IO Int]. Let's say the list consists of 4 numbers (e.g. `[3, 5, 2, 3]`). I would then like to generate the output `3, 5, 2, 3` where it could also be the case that I may need to convert a number into a letter (hence they need to become chars). I have tried for some time now to do this but I haven't found any solution yet. How would I go about this?

Comment: A list of `[IO Int]` is not a list of numbers, it's a list of ways to get a number. For example the first element can be "read one from the console" and the second element can also be "read one from the console" and the third element can be "open myInt.txt and read one from there"

Comment: It often does *not* make much sense to have an `[IO a]`, since that is a list of `IO` actions. Usually that should be `IO [Int]`). `[IO Int]` would be used of you have a list of *handlers*, not a list of `Int`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do something to the Int in [IO Int], you can first use `sequence` to turn it into `IO [Int]`, then use do notation to manipulate the [Int] conveniently.

```
myFunc :: IO ()
myFunc = do
  randInts <- sequence (someFunctionThatCreatesListOfIOInt) -- here the type of randInts is [Int]
  let result = pureFunctionOnInts randInts
  print result
```

Thanks the comment that pointed out `randomRIO (0, 5)` produces IO Int instead a list of them. In this case, it is more convenient to work with it individually rather than having a list of IO actions.

Note that you (almost) *cannot* turn `IO a` into `a` because this breaks referential transparency. Of course, there are unsafe functions that do that, but it's ill-advised to use them unless you are absolutely sure on what are you doing.

Edit: to get the four random numbers, you can do the following:

```
myFunc = do
  randInts <- replicateM 4 (randomIO (0, 5 :: Int)) -- here are four random integers between 0 and 5
  let result = doSomethingToInts randInts
  print result
```

Of course, you can return the result instead of printing it so that it can be binded with other IO actions.

Comment: actually, `randomRIO (0, 5::Int)` has type `IO Int` and not `[IO Int]`

Comment: OK, I was quite rusty on that, will edit it now.